# "If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files" Error with Docker Grafana deployment behind reverse proxy

Tags: docker, grafana, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have been trying to get my Grafana container to work with my reverse proxy but have had no success. Everything i try just results in the "If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files" page appearing regardless of it I access it using the internal IP or the external URL for it.

My Docker Compose in entertainer as of now, note that none of those enviroment variables are in use right now hence the #

```
version: '2'
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    hostname: grafana
    container_name: grafana
    network_mode: le_bridge
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    #environment: 
      #GF_SERVER_DOMAIN: 'myurl.ddns.net'
      #GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: 'https://myurl.ddns.net:443/grafana'   
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: 
      - /Docker_Configs/grafana/config:/etc/grafana
      - /Docker_Configs/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana
```

My grafana.ini

```
[server]
domain = myurl.ddns.net
root_url = https://myurl.ddns.net/grafana/
```

My reverse proxy config

```
location /grafana/{
   include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
   proxy_pass http://192.168.2.13:3000/;
```

Comment: Are you setting the auth proxy settings and making your reverse proxy pass auth data?

Comment: Do grafana  logs show anything?

Answer (score 4):

If using docker, use following settings in environment to get this done.

```
GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=https://myurl.ddns.net:443/grafana/
GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This broke for me when upgrading from 7.2.0 to 7.3.1. The issue is that grafana is listening on port 3000 and your reverse proxy is on port 443. Grafana is looking for assets on port 443 of the grafana host (where it is not listening) instead of on 3000 (where it *is* listening).

The fix is to add the external port to the `root_url` param in `grafana.ini`.

```
root_url = https://myurl.ddns.net:443/grafana/
```

Then grafana will understand that the port used by the reverse proxy and grafana itself are different, and behave correctly.

Comment: Upgraded from 7.1.4 to 7.3.1, this did not solve the problem...

Comment: Upgraded to 8.2.1 and had to use server name instead of ip in root_url and that fixed this issue.