# Grafana Embed (iframe) via XHR throught HAProxy : Grafana has failed to load its application files

Tags: docker, iframe, embed, grafana, haproxy

We are trying to develop a solution which allows to see grafana iframes (embed) in a web app (angular).

**Front-End context :**

- We are logged-in in the web page for security purpose.
- We want to display  element with grafana source (our grafana server).
- We want the iframe to display some grafana dashobards while being authentified as a grafana user
- To do so we need to add a "X-WEBAUTH-USER" header to the request
- We did it using XMLHttpRequest, setting the url to our server, adding the requested header and then adding the url to an iframe element.

Here is the code :

html :

[image: html code]

ts:
[image: Typescript code]

**Architecture Context :**

- Working with Docker each piece (nginx server for front end, grafana , haproxy ) has its own container.

  **HAProxy :**
- Front-End xhr request comes from client browser and goes to http://..fr
- HAProxy intercepts the request to redirect it to the grafana container
- We are using Haproxy CORS module to allow xhr's freflight request

> ```
> frontend http-proxy
>   mode http
>   bind *:80
>   http-request lua.cors "*" "*" "*"
>   http-response lua.cors
>   acl is_grafana req.hdr(Host) -i -m beg <grafana-host>.<domain>
>   use_backend grafana if is_grafana
>
> backend grafana
>   mode http
>   server static <grafana-container-host>:3000 check
> ```

**Grafana :**

- Proxy Auth is activated :

> ```
> [auth.proxy]
> enabled = true
> header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER
> header_property = username
> auto_sign_up = false
> ldap_sync_ttl = 60
> sync_ttl = 60
> whitelist = 
> headers = 
> enable_login_token = false
> ```

- Anonymous Auth is disabled:

> ```
>   [auth.anonymous]
>   # enable anonymous access
>   enabled = false
>   # specify organization name that should be used for unauthenticated users
>   org_name = Main Org.
>   # specify role for unauthenticated users
>   org_role = Viewer
>   # mask the Grafana version number for unauthenticated users
>   hide_version = false
> ```

**Problem :**
The iframe does not display the dashboard but we get this message instead :

> If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files
>
> - This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
> - If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath. If not using a reverse proxy make sure to set serve_from_sub_path to true.
> - If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn build
> - Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help
> - Check if you are using a non-supported browser. For more information, refer to the list of supported browsers.

There is no error in the dev console.

If we directly go to the grafana web app (http://..fr) we dont get this message, it works fine.

**What we tried :**

- Reboot grafana server (no changes)
- Browsers used are supported (Chrome, Firefox)
- We are not using a subpath so it is set to false in grafana conf :
  `serve_from_sub_path = false`
- We tried applying a subpath in haproxy to check it but we got the same result

**Other topics suggestions :**

- https://community.grafana.com/t/nginx-reverse-proxy-with-ssl-leads-to-failed-to-load-application-files/20726/4

=> Here is our conf :

```
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/
domain = <grafana-host>.<domain>.fr
```

- ["If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files" Error with Docker Grafana deployment behind reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218153/if-youre-seeing-this-grafana-has-failed-to-load-its-application-files-error-w) :

> If using docker, use following settings in environment to get this done.
> GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=https://myurl.ddns.net:443/grafana/
> GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH=true
> => We have already set this in Grafana config file instead.

> The issue is that grafana is listening on port 3000 and your reverse proxy is on port 443.
> Grafana is looking for assets on port 443 of the grafana host (where it is not listening) instead of on 3000 (where it is listening).
> The fix is to add the external port to the root_url param in grafana.ini
> root_url = https://myurl.ddns.net:443/grafana/

=> We tried to add this too but still not working thought.

- https://forums.percona.com/t/if-youre-seeing-this-grafana-has-failed-to-load-its-application-files/8614

> This issue is resolved after extending the disk space.

=> There is enought free space disk.

Answer (score 0):

You have very naive auth implementation. You will open dashboard URL in the iframe succesfully. But dashboard page loads a lot of JS/CSS files, API calls, which are not authenticated via `X-WEBAUTH-USER`, so they very likely failing to load = error `Grafana has failed to load its application files` is valid in this case.

You should to redesign your authentication concept from the scratch. Your current aproach will not work as you see + it is insecure. (BTW, some ideas: https://github.com/jangaraj/grafana-iframe)